# how to bind control to json model in sapui

Tags: sapui5

> why can't i use these `sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel) and
>   this.getView().setModel("oModel","someModel")`  in functions other
>   than life cycle hooks of controller in sapui5.
>
> I am trying to bind model to the controls of my view without giving it
>   an id. so i want to make a model and set that model to the view where
>   i will bind.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>Handler Context in JavaScript Views</title>

        <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
                type="text/javascript"
                src="https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
        >
        </script>

        <script>
            jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageToast");
            sap.ui.jsview("local.view", {
                getControllerName: function() {
                    return "local.controller";
                },
                createContent: function(oController) {                    
     var oText=new sap.m.Text();
     oText.bindProperty("text","oModel>/myData");
     
     var oInput=new sap.m.Input();
     oInput.bindValue("oModel>/myData");
     
     var oIn=new sap.m.Input();
     oIn.bindValue("oModel>/myData");
     
     var oBar=new sap.m.Bar({contentLeft:oIn,contentMiddle:oText});
     var oButton=new sap.m.Button({text:"press to reset",
        press:function(){
         oController.resetModel();
        }
        });
     var oPage=new sap.m.Page({headerContent:[oInput],footer:oBar,showNavButton:true,content:[oButton]});
     var oShell=new sap.m.App({pages:oPage});
     return oShell;
                }
            });
   
   
   
            sap.ui.controller("local.controller", {
    onInit:function(){
     var aData={"myData":"enter!!"};
     
     var oModel=new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
     oModel.setData(aData);
     sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel,"oModel");
    },
    resetModel:function(){
     var oModel=sap.ui.getCore().getModel("oModel");
     oModel.oData.myData="Reset";    
    }
            });
            sap.ui.view({
                type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS,
                viewName: "local.view"
            }).placeAt("uiArea");
        </script>

    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="uiArea"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

how can i update my model which is bound to other controls on button press

Is there any way to access controls in controller of my view without giving it an id?
Regards,
Ajaay

Comment: You can definitely use these function calls inside a view or a controller. Maybe this.getView().setModel... is not working because you are inside the wrong context. In other words 'this' might be pointing to an object different than the one you're thinking.

Could you please post the code of your view and controller?

Comment: Thanks fabiopagoti for your reply,i got what you said.:)

Comment: hey i have the code inserted please check out:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are updating your model incorrectly.

Remember, you should *never ever* use the internal `<yourModel>.oData.<yourProperty> = <whatever>`, but instead always use:
`<yourModel>.setProperty("<propertyName>", <value>)`.
That way you will be absolutely certain your model will be updated with the new values

Change your resetModel method to

```
resetModel:function(){
    var oModel=sap.ui.getCore().getModel("oModel");
    oModel.setProperty("/myData", "Reset");             
}
```

and it will work

Comment: Thanks Qualiture i got it working.Can you please explain why should  not i use <yourModel>.oData.<yourProperty> = <whatever>

Comment: If you use `<yourModel>.oData.<yourProperty> = <whatever>`, you are in essence updating only the internal representation of the model. I.e., the internal values are updated, but this update is unknown to the outside world. When using the `setData()` or `setProperty()` methods, this will not only update your model (the `oData.<whatever>` property will be updated like you have done as well), but depending on the binding type it will also notify any bound controls of the update, and reflect the changes accordingly

Comment: Thanks Qualiture for explaining i got it now :)!

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few questions that you have asked here, so let me break it down

1. *Why can't i use these sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel) and
   this.getView().setModel("oModel","someModel") in functions other than life cycle hooks of controller in sapui5.* - **You can access them**

   I'm not sure of where exactly you are facing an issue to use `sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel)`, but for `this.getView().setModel("oModel","someModel")` I can say what @fabiopagoti has commented, that you are probably using it in the wrong context.
   Here's anexample,

   `onInit : function()
   {
      /* 'this' refers to the controller here,
        */
     var oController = this;
     myOwnFunction : function()
        {
          /* 'this' now refers to the scope inside 'onInit'
              Therefore this.getView().setModel() won't work.
           oController.getView().setModel() will work. */
        }
   }`
2. *Is there any way to access controls in controller of my view without giving it an id?* - **Yes**, only if the View is a JavaScript view

   In your **view.js** instead of declaring a variable as,

   `var oVariable;`

   Declare it as,

   `this.oVariable;`

   And anywhere you need to access it in the **controller.js** (inside the controller's context) access the variable as,

   `this.getView().oVariable;`
3. *How can i update my model which is bound to other controls on button press*

   `resetModel:function()
      {
           var oModel=sap.ui.getCore().getModel("oModel");
           oModel.setProperty("/myData", "Reset" );

   }`

The setProperty documentation is [here](http://veui5infra.dhcp.wdf.sap.corp:8080/demokit/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#setProperty)